# How to align any number of child elements uniformly across the entire width within the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list of elements and a layout at the bottom of the screen. This layout contains some `ImageButtons`. It looks in such a way:

[image: Layout]

Here is my markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cloudListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cloud_list_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cloud_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_copy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cloud_copy_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_paste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cloud_paste_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cloud_delete_selector" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to align my `ImageButtons` uniformly across the entire width. I now have three buttons but they may be more or less. Is it possible to apply some universal markup to the bottom layout that provides uniform aligning across the with for any number of buttons? For three buttons it must look like this:

[image: Layout]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `android:layout_weight="1"` to all the `ImageButton` and change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: It does not look like a solution. All three elements are simply stretched to fill the entire space.

Comment: Try changing `android:background="@drawable/cloud_copy_selector"` to `android:src="@drawable/cloud_copy_selector"`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the weight property.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_copy"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cloud_copy_selector" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_paste"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cloud_paste_selector" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_cloud_delete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cloud_delete_selector" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
 />
```

Comment: It does not look like a solution. All three elements are simply stretched to fill the entire space.

Comment: this is exactly the same as the solution you checked as accepted ¬¬